# How do I reference this ref in React?

Tags: reactjs, ref

I have a React component which it utilizing react-bootstrap-table with customized checkboxes for each table cell. I am trying to ensure that all checkboxes are unchecked on componentDidMount, and to do that I need to target the checkbox ref. However, the component came with the following code for each checkbox, and I don't know how I can reference this ref:

```
<input
          type={ type }
          name={ 'checkbox' + rowIndex }
          id={ 'checkbox' + rowIndex }
          checked={ checked }
          disabled={ disabled }
          onChange={ e=> onChange(e, rowIndex) }
          ref={ input => {
            if (input) {
              input.indeterminate = props.indeterminate;
           }
          }}
         />
```

I have tried a bunch of variations of getDOMNode but am getting errors saying "Cannot read property 'getDOMNode' of undefined". Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using the `indeterminate` parameter?

Comment: I don't know that I am. I'm a relative newbie and don't really have experience with "intedeterminate". For the sake of discussion let's say that I am using it because the checkbox component came pre-scripted with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function [`createRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#creating-refs) to create a ref to the input.

`indeterminate` is a property that has to be set from javascript itself, relying on the props as in your example, a case for that would be in `componentDidMount` lifecycle.

Here is a demo of that:

```js
const { Component, createRef } = React;
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.checkboxRef = createRef();
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    if(this.checkboxRef.current) {
      this.checkboxRef.current.indeterminate = this.props.indeterminate;
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        ref={this.checkboxRef}
      />
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App indeterminate={true} />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.7.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try this now.

Comment: This works with no errors thus far but am still unable to reference that checkbox ref. All I want to do is make sure all of the checkboxes produced by that component are unchecked when the component is loaded.

Comment: You seem to be giving it a `checked` attribute, so what is the `ref` for? Initialising the `checked` attribute to `false` should work